# How to overload << for a vector of structures

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm having trouble with the syntax for a homework program. The prompt is to overload an inserter in such a way that it can properly execute the program fragment:

`for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
     cout << v[i] << endl;
cout << endl;`

So, this is what I have so far, but I still get an error at the cout << v[i] statement (Invalid operands to binary expression):

```
    unsigned int seed;
    struct node
    {
         int integer;
         double value;
    };

    double random(unsigned int &seed);
    void initialize_vector(vector<node> &v);
    template<typename T>
    void print_vector(const vector<T> &v);
    template<typename T>
    ostream &operator <<(ostream &out, const vector<T> &v);
    template<typename T>
    void output(ostream &out, const vector<T> &v);

    int main()
    {
        vector<node> v(10);

        initialize_vector(v);
        print_vector(v);

        return 0;
    }

    double random(unsigned int &seed)
    {
        const int MODULUS = 15749;
        const int MULTIPLIER = 69069;
        const int INCREMENT = 1;

        seed = ((MULTIPLIER * seed) + INCREMENT) % MODULUS;

        return double(seed) / double(MODULUS);
    }

    void initialize_vector(vector<node> &v)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        {
            v[i].integer = int (11 * random(seed));
            v[i].value = double (11 * random(seed));
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    void print_vector(const vector<T> &v)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
            cout << v[i] << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }

    template<typename T>
    ostream &operator <<(ostream &out, const vector<T> &v)
    {
        output(out, v);
        return (out);
    }

    template<typename T>
    void output(ostream &out, const vector<T> &v)
    {
        cout << v.integer;
        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(6) << v.value;
    }
```

I've tried passing node instead of T, along with passing with and without const references for the last 3 functions, so again I assume my syntax in the void output function is wrong somehow. Any help or points in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

*Note: I can't change the ostream &operator function.

Comment: You have never told the computer how to output a `node` type. What do you mean by “I can’t change the ostream &operator function”? I assume you mean the `operator<<(ostream&, foo)` function? You have already changed/added it for _all_ vectors. Why can you not specialize over a `const node&`?

Comment: node needs an `ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const node& n);`

Comment: @Dúthomhas I just can't change what's within the function because that is what my professor provided for me. When you mean specialize over `const node&`, would I not have to use `template<typename T>` then? and @Aluan would that be another function, or would I be modifying my original `operator <<` function?

Comment: Wait nevermind, I got it. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  cout << v[i] << endl;
```

If v is a vector of node, then you need one more function to overload operator << for a node

```
ostream &operator <<(ostream &out, const node &n)
{
    out << n.interger << " " << n.value;
    return out;
}
```